# Keyboard don't open to EditBox in android

Tags: android

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ReceitaOnlineUI" 
android:background="@color/color1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_busca_receita_online"
                android:layout_width="212dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:entries="@array/opcao_busca_receita" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTeste"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/myfirstfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside the FrameLayout I open this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/searchbyname_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearchByName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/dica_search_by_name" >

</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFindOnLine"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's is how I open the fragment in the OnCreate of a FragmentActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myfirstfragment, myFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG_STRING)
.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
.commit();
```

When I click into the EditText, the keyboard don't appear! In the bar from android, I see it open it, because the icon from keyboard is there...but I don't see it in the screen...

Someone know what I need to do, to show???

EDIT: Seems that the EditText need lost the focus, to the keyboard show...

Comment: Are you testing on an actual device or an emulator?

Comment: In my device and in an emulator =/

Comment: How are you adding the second layout to the `FrameLayout` with id `myfirstfragment`? Can you post that code please?

Comment: Yeah! Already post it!  I don't know why, but in my device it appears that is working now....